# PHP 5.6 returning results like PHP 5.2

Tags: php, server, devops

We recently occured weird error like:

`json_decode(): integer overflow detected in Command line code on line 1`

On our server with PHP 5.6.30(unforunately i don't know how it was built).

We had code like `json_decode('{"key":999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999}', true)`

What actually happened that we indeed had too big integer value. But what was interesting i run this code on 3v4l and in case of too big integer it should be converted to float - https://3v4l.org/IdJpZ

But what is more interesting that on php 5.2.0-5.2.3 it actually converts this number to max integer value instead, like:

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  int(9223372036854775807)
}
```

So this is exactly output from this code and `php -v`:

```
$ php -r "var_dump(json_decode('{\"key\":999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999}', true));"
PHP Notice:  json_decode(): integer overflow detected in Command line code on line 1
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  int(9223372036854775807)
}
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 08:50:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Do you have any idea why our PHP 5.6.30 did the same behavior as PHP 5.2.0-5.2.3?

Also we use extension which actually requries at least PHP 5.4 and it works fine. Also we are using things like `[]` and it works fine too.

Comment: If you can use it the key value as string you wont have that problem - [example](https://3v4l.org/JdMvP)

Comment: you cleared that the apache module has the same version then the cli?

Comment: This is not answering my question.

Comment: @netzding i run this code in php cli as you see, this is result from `php -r` Not from apache module and/or php-fpm or something else.

Comment: Is your system a 32bit system or a 64 bit system?

Comment: 64 bit, but still - as you see on 3v4l we should get there float, not integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured out what is going on. We actually have jsonc extension which is drop-in replacement for native json support in php.

This issue actually pointed me to good direction - https://github.com/remicollet/pecl-json-c/issues/13

Indeed we just have outdated jsonc version and that's it.

```
$ php --ri json

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.3.6
JSON-C headers version => 0.11.99
JSON-C library version => 0.11.99
```